# I'm using a shared server, and as such Gmail marks my email as spam (all from headers are different from the same IP)

Tags: email, spam, spam-prevention, gmail

I have a shared server, meaning many people share the same IP.

When I send an email, the `@website.com` is different from someone else that shares the same IP with me, therefore Gmail marks it as spam.

For example:

- My website's IP is `1.2.3.4`. My website is `mywebsite.com`
- Person 2's website's IP is hosted by the same host, and as such their IP is `1.2.3.4`
- Person 2's website is `person2.com`. When they send an email, it gets sent from `theiremail@person2.com`
- When I send an email, it gets sent from `myemail@mywebsite.com`
- According to Gmail's spam thing: "Use the same address in the 'From:' header on every bulk mail you send."

Again, the only similarities between our websites is the IP. However, this causes Gmail to mark both our mail as spam.

Is there a way to sort this out with Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be mis-interpreting [Gmail's suggestions](http://www.google.com/intl/ar/mail/help/bulk_mail.html), as "Use the same address in the 'From:' header on every bulk mail you send" is something they're suggesting you *should* do, not something they're saying to avoid.

It's quite common for mail servers to send out emails for multiple domains, so I'd be surprised if this was a particularly high spam indicator. The issues you're having are more likely to relate to the content of the email, recipients marking the messages as spam, or other factors.

It might be worth looking up the IP of your server using a service like http://senderscore.org/ or http://www.senderbase.org. These will tell you if your server IP is on any blacklists, which might be an indicator that one of the other sites on the server has been sending spam.